# Трудности при расчете включений

Tags: python, numpy

Столкнулся с трудностью при расчете включений. Ниже привожу пример в котором после создания линий
xn и y0 строится график ниже:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 8)
y = 10*np.sinc(x*2+4)

xn = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
y0 = 10*np.sinc(xn*2+4)
```

```
fq = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
ynq = fq(xn)
fc = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
ync = fc(xn)

plt.plot(xn, ynq)
plt.plot(xn, ync)
plt.show()
```

Но проблема в том, что включения по каким то причинам строятся не по xn и y0. Очевидно что так делать неполучится, если использовать первоначальные данные для расчета xn и y0.

Вопрос - как по указаному выше способу построить вышеперечисленные графики?

Comment: Эээ. Вообще-то у вас там всё правильно происходит. Нарисуйте график `plt.plot(x, y)` и увидите, что интерполяция делалась по ограниченному числу точек, а графики ваши нарисованы именно что интерполированной функцией, но по большему кол-ву точек, более детально. Конечно, интерполированные графики проходят через точки, по которым строилась интерполяция, ну так в этом и её смысл.

Comment: Да, и ещё можете график `plt.plot(xn, y0)` построить и увидеть, что он немного отличается от интерполяций. У вас `(x,y)` - это подмножество `(xn,y0)`, по которому строится интерполяционная функция. Потом эта функция применяется на `xn` и получается что-то похожее на `y0` в результате. Вы разберитесь, в чём суть интерполяции, зачем это всё и что у вас где.

Comment: Я так и не понимаю вопрос. Хотите построить интерполяцию по `(xn,y0)`? Пожалуйста: `fn = interpolate.interp1d(xn, y0, kind='quadratic')` и потом смотрите график `plt.plot(xn, fn(xn))`, так ещё точнее интерполяция будет, чем по `(x,y)`, потому что точек больше гораздо.

Comment: Ну, не совсем равный получится результат, получится ещё более точная интерполяция. А где "результат не верный"?

Comment: Это **одна и та же функция** просто на подробном наборе точек и на выборочном наборе, они почти совпадают. Какое пересечение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тоже не ответ на ваш вопрос, скорее, комментарий с картинками.

Ваш вопрос непонятен. Интерполяционная кривая построена по точкам из массивов `x` и `y`. Чтобы убедиться, что она проходит через эти точки, достаточно вычислить выражения:

`y - fq(x)` -> `[0.0, 1.110e-16, -5.551e-17, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0]`

Видно, что в заданных точках разница между эталоном `y` и функцией `fq` равна нулю. Аналогично для `fc`:

`y - fc(x)` -> `[ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 2.776e-17, -5.551e-17, 0.0]`

В том, что интерполяционная функция в остальных точках не совпадает с эталонной, нет ничего удивительного.

Функция `sinc` есть сумма полинома с бесконечным числом членов `sinc x = 1 - x^2/3! + x^4/5! - x^6/7! + ...`, поэтому её в принципе нельзя представить в виде суммы конечного числа полиномов второй и третьей степеней.

Поэтому ни квадратичная интерполяция, ни кубическая не смогут быть равными `y0` в точках `xn` (за исключением точек из `x`). Графики это убедительно иллюстрируют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы поняли, почему это теперь называется "включения" после редактирования вопроса? О чём же нас всё-таки хотел спросить автор?

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня сложилось впечатление, что ТС ожидал от интерполяции полного совпадения с эталоном. И вопрос был "как же так! Почему они не совпадают?"

Answer (score 1):

Я из вопроса и комментариев так и не смог понять, в чём у вас проблема. Но давайте попробую что-то пояснить. Напишу для этого лучше свой код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# кто-то знает функцию f и заготавливает нам массив точек (x,y)
def f(x):
    return 10*np.sinc(x*2+4)

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 8)
y = f(x)

# тут мы уже как бы ничего не знаем про f и пытаемся её смоделировать по (x,y)
f_int = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

# расширенный набор точек и значения f_int на нём
x_new = np.linspace(0, 2, 800)
y_new = f_int(x_new)

# рисуем всё
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, 'r--')
plt.plot(x_new, f(x_new), 'g-')
```

[image: интерполяция]

Итак, что мы имеем. Допустим, есть некая функция `f`, которую мы не знаем, но кто-то взял несколько точек `x`, посчитал на них `y = f(x)` и предоставил нам два массива `x` и `y`. Я нарисовал эти точки на графике.

Далее мы взяли эти два массива и прикинули - а какая функция могла бы нам дать `y = f(x)` на этом наборе точек. Получилась функция `f_int`. После чего мы сделали между точками массива `x` много промежуточных точек, чтобы получше рассмотреть функцию на графике, получили массив `x_new`. И дальше мы вычисляем на этих точках `y_new = f_int(x_new)` и рисуем график `(x_new, y_new)`.

Кроме того, я нарисовал исходную функцию на том же расширенном наборе точек, чтобы мы её могли сравнить с тем, что у нас получилось.

Как можно видеть на графике, обе функции и изначальная `f` и `f_int` полученная интерполированием на наборе `(x,y)` проходят через точки из набора `(x,y)` и они весьма похожи. Так и должно быть с интерполяцией.

Comment: @leo_p Погодите, что-то одно неизвестно - либо функция (это та ситуация, которую я описал в ответе), либо точки (но тогда у нас есть функция, через которую мы можем всё вычислись). Если неизвестна ни функция, ни точки - то что же тогда известно вообще? )))

Comment: @leo_p OK. Есть функция. Зачем тогда интерполяция вообще? У вас есть функция - можно с ней делать что угодно. Что вы хотите? А, может быть вы хотите найти обратную функцию? Если точки на `y`, есть функция `f`, может вы хотите найти такие `x`, что `y = f(x)`?

Comment: @leo_p А каких точек, точек чего? Есть функция, можно построить её график (на любом промежутке). Какие именно точки на графике функции вы хотите найти?

Comment: Интерполяцию вы можете строить по любым точкам, по вашему выбору. Вам нужно чётко сформулировать задачу. Дано: то-то и то-то. Хочу получить: то-то и то-то. Например: есть исходная функция, есть интерполяционная функция, хочу узнать, по каким точкам строилась интерполяционная функция (т.е. где эти две функции пересекаются). Может быть так? Опять же - при этом дан набор точек, на которых нужно проверять это пересечение или он произвольный? Вообще это будет непростая задача - вон эти функции прямо отрезками совпадают, а не точками.

Comment: Я уже почти понимаю. И могу написать другой ответ. Только вы чётко сформулируйте задачу. Итак, что дано и что нужно получить?

Comment: `y0` - это не функция! Это набор значений исходной функции в неких точках `xn`. Это тоже самое, что `y`, просто в `y0` точек больше, в которых посчитана функция. Хорошо, дан набор значений `y0`. Что дальше? )